# Apply different color on two parts of input range

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to create a seek bar for the video and I want to show black color on the seek bar representing the amount of video which has been downloaded. How can I assign an additional color on the seek bar representing the amount of video downloaded?

I think I didn't explain my question properly. I want a color (e.g. silver) which shows the amount of video which has been downloaded for playing. Silver color on the seek bar can be found in the default `html5 video` and `YouTube video player`. (Image provided below)

```js
var player = document.querySelector("video"),
    seek_bar = document.querySelector("input"),
    _console = document.querySelector("div");

player.ontimeupdate = function() {
  seek_bar.value = this.currentTime.toString().split(".")[0];
}
player.addEventListener('progress', function() {
  try {
    _console.innerHTML = "Downloaded Upto: " + this.buffered.end(0).toString().split(".")[0];
  } catch(e) {}
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 90%;
  height: 75%;
}
input[type="range"] {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgb(110, 170, 250);
  border: 1px solid rgb(15, 15, 15);
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: rgb(15, 15, 15);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <video src="https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1920x1080_60fps_12000k.mp4" controls></video>
  <input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="634"/>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`SILVER (THE OTHER COLOR) ON THE SEEK_BAR:`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of something similar I did a couple of years ago:
https://jsfiddle.net/remisture/esyvws3d/

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  // Get the current width of the slider
  var sliderWidth = $('[type=range]').width();

  // Remove previously created style elements
  $('.custom-style-element-related-to-range').remove();

  // Add our updated styling
  $('<style class="custom-style-element-related-to-range">input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb { box-shadow: -' + sliderWidth + 'px 0 0 ' + sliderWidth + 'px;}<style/>').appendTo('head');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}

input[type='range'] {
  width: 100%;
}

/*Chrome*/

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  input[type='range'] {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #9a905d;
  }
  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #13bba4;
    margin-top: -1px;
  }
  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background: #434343;
    color: #43e5f7;
  }
}


/** FF*/

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: #43e5f7;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: #9a905d;
}


/* IE*/

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: #43e5f7;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background-color: #9a905d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="range">
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what OP wants then you need multiple colored ranges on the progress bar. User can move the video seek bar all over the place and browser could load portions of videos that are not consecutive.

Comment: The question is about setting a color for parts of the input.

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question specifically. So I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use the HTML [`progress`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiP96-H_eXhAhXE5eAKHbA5CvIQFjABegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTML%2FElement%2Fprogress&usg=AOvVaw2Ai9SaJ-XRDENTxljisGoq) element.

Here is how you would style it if you wanted the meter showing the amount of video downloaded to have black color.

```
progress
  -webkit-appearance: none /* Important, otherwise your styles won't have effect */

progress::-webkit-progress-value
  background: black
```

[Here's a live Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/merkur0/pen/yrxoGL?editors=1111)

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question specifically. So I have updated the question.